# Grep ignore special characters before applying regular expression

Tags: json, bash, shell, grep

***General***

I am trying to recursively search through hundreds of JSON files under a specific directory for lines that match a specific regular expression.

**grep -rh** works great for searching recursively for specific lines. I am having a problem applying a regular expression with the search because all the lines in the JSON files begin with a **"** and end in either **",** or **"**.

Example: If I want to apply a regular expression to get all the lines that begin with **zxc** I will not be able to do it because the lines actually begin with **"zxc**

***Code***

The following command would work if the lines had no **"** at the beginning.

```
/bin/grep -rh -E "^(zxc)" "/etc/json_dir/"
```

The following command works, but I do not want grep to get hundreds of thousands of lines from all the JSON files and then apply a regular expression afterwards.

```
/bin/grep -rh -E ".*" "/etc/json_dir/" | /bin/sed -e 's/^"//g' -e 's/,$//g' -e 's/"$//g' | /bin/grep -E "^(zxc)"
```

***Question***

Is there a way for grep to ignore the **"** character at the beginning and **"** and **",** characters at the end of the lines before it applies a regular expression ?

If there's no way, is there a way to do it with some other bash command, perl, python or some other language.

Comment: Use a tool that can handle JSON correctly. Use `jq` and not `grep`, `sed`, `awk` ...

Comment: Agree with Cyrus. Nevertheless: `grep -E '^"?zxc' ...` will handle an *optional* quote at the start of line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with `awk` if I understand Your question properly:

```
awk '{gsub(/^"|"$/,"") } # this part removes all the "s from the start and end of line
     /^WHAT/ { print } # or any other processing
     ' **/*.json
```

*Note*: the `**/*` requires the `globestar` recursive globbing option in (modern) `bash`.

See it in action at [Ideone](https://www.ideone.com/Kdcarw).

You can shorten it somewhat to:

```
awk '/^"?WHAT/' **/* # this executes the default printing action
```

But `awk|sed|grep` might not be the right tool to search JSON.

Comment: Oh wow, this awk command is amazing. Thank you for sharing it. This should do it for me.

I am actually using jq for parsing JSON, but I am not aware of jq reading many JSON files at once without using a loop. Maybe I should do some research on that.